# Issue with swapping elements in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm trying to swap the contents of two headers in a table by drag. But the logic that I wrote is working intermitently. The reason seems to be that somehow, `mouseup` is being captured twice and so the event enters twice.
Below is my code.

```
var resizePressed = false;
var dragPressed = false;
var $start;
var startX, startWidth, mouseOverIndex, startIndex;
var swapped;   

$('.col-resize-anchor').mousedown(function (e) {
    $start = $(this.parentElement.parentElement);
    resizePressed = true;
    startX = e.pageX;
    startWidth = $(this.parentElement.parentElement).width();
});

$('table th').one('mousedown', function (e) {
    startIndex = this.cellIndex;
    $start = $(this);
    swapped = false;
    dragPressed = true;
    startX = e.pageX;
    startWidth = $(this.parentElement.parentElement).width();
});
$('table th').one('mousemove', function (e) {
    if (resizePressed) {
        $($start).width(startWidth + (e.pageX - startX));
    }
});
$('table th').hover(function (e) {
    mouseOverIndex = this.cellIndex;
});
$('table th').one('mouseup', function () {
    var $firstValue;
    if (resizePressed) {
        resizePressed = false;
    }
    if (dragPressed && !swapped) {
        dragPressed = false;
        if (mouseOverIndex !== undefined && (startIndex !== mouseOverIndex)) {
            $firstValue = $('th')[startIndex].firstChild.firstChild.innerHTML;
            $('th')[startIndex].firstChild.firstChild.innerHTML = $('th')[mouseOverIndex].firstChild.firstChild.innerHTML;
            $('th')[mouseOverIndex].firstChild.firstChild.innerHTML = $firstValue;
            swapped = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: BTW, the issue occurs if there are more than 2 columns.

Comment: can u put ur code in jsfiddle ?

Comment: You're traversing the DOM **4** times only to get two specific `<th>`s (`$('th')[...].firstChild.firstChild.innerHTML ...`). Grab them once and store them in a variable: `var tableHeadColumns = $("th"); tableHeadColumns[...].firstChild.firstChild.innerHTML`

Comment: How come you are using `.one()`? Is this drag n drop only happening once?

Comment: I tried to contain the operation to only once to see if that might work. Didn't work

Comment: @Andreas I didn't get you won't they change for ever mouse up? even if I store them in a var. Does it have anything to do with my issue?

Comment: You could either move the line `var tableHeadColums = ...` into the `if (dragPressed && !swapped) { ... }` block or use the good old [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) which returns a live collection of the DOM. The content/order of the collection will always be the same as the one currently in the DOM. And no, this has nothing to do with your problem. Just a bit of a code smell, imho :)